# Only run one test case in a Junit test from the command line

Tags: maven, junit

Say I have this JUnit test file:

```
package huru;


import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.junit.VertxUnitRunner;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.Arrays;

@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class AsyncTest {


  @Test
  public void testParallel(TestContext tc) {
      // ...
  }

  @Test
  public void testSeries(TestContext tc) {
     // ...
  }

}
```

*using the command line, is there a way to only run the testSeries test case?*

Right now, I am using:

```
mvn test -Dexec.mainClass="huru.util.Async"
```

but this will run both test cases, I only want to run one test case at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [maven surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)

Since 2.7.3, you can execute a limited number of methods in the test by adding #myMethod or #my*ethod. For example, `-Dtest=MyTest#myMethod`.

This is supported for junit 4.x and TestNg.